# why compiling a dynamic library error in this situation?

Tags: c++, linux, .so

I have written two files  on the same path.
the first file named "dso.h".

```
//dso.cpp
#ifdef DSO_H
#define DSO_H

#include <string>
#include <map>

#include "spider.h"

using namespace std;

#define MODULE_OK  0
#define MODULE_ERR 1

#define MAGIC_MAJOR_NUMBER 1
#define MAGIC_MINOR_NUMBER 0

#define STANDARD_MODULE_STUFF MAGIC_MAJOR_NUMBER, MAGIC_MINOR_NUMBER,__FILE__


typedef struct Module{
        int version;
        int minor_version;
        const char * name;
        void (*init)(Module *);
        int (*handle)(void *);
} MODULE;


class ModuleManager
{
        public:
                ModuleManager();
                ~ModuleManager();

                int load(string path, string name);  
                MODULE * getModule(string name);

        private:
                map<string, MODULE*> m_modules; 
};


#endif
```

the second file named "testmodule.cpp"

```
#include "dso.h"
#include <stdio.h>

extern int handle(void * data){
        printf("%s", (char *)data);
        return MODULE_OK;
}

extern int init(Module * module){
        module = &module;
        return MODULE_OK;
}


Module mod
{
        MODULE_MAJOR_VERSION,
        MODULE_SUB_VERSION,
        __FILE__,
        init,
        handle,
};
```

I try to run this command:

> g++ -shared -fPIC  -o testmodule.so testmodule.cpp

After running that command, I get some errors, see below

```
testmodule.cpp: In function ‘int handle(void*)’:
testmodule.cpp:6:10: error: ‘MODULE_OK’ was not declared in this scope
   return MODULE_OK;
          ^~~~~~~~~
testmodule.cpp: At global scope:
testmodule.cpp:9:17: warning: ‘init’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
 extern int init(Module * module){
                 ^~~~~~
testmodule.cpp:9:17: error: ‘Module’ was not declared in this scope
testmodule.cpp:9:17: note: suggested alternative: ‘double’
 extern int init(Module * module){
                 ^~~~~~
                 double
testmodule.cpp:9:26: error: ‘module’ was not declared in this scope
 extern int init(Module * module){
                          ^~~~~~
testmodule.cpp:9:26: note: suggested alternative: ‘double’
 extern int init(Module * module){
                          ^~~~~~
                          double
testmodule.cpp:15:1: error: ‘Module’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘double’?
 Module mod
 ^~~~~~
 double
```

I can't get the dynamic library , how to fix the problem ?

running above command in ubuntu18.04TLS  linux.

Comment: You have shown the contents of what you claim is `dso.cpp`, which is a *source file*. That contents looks like it should be in a *header file* named `dso.h`. And `testmodule.cpp` include the *header file* `dso.h`, not the source file.

Comment: There are other (logical) errors in your `testmodule.cpp` code by the way. Like the order of definitions and declarations, as well as you forget that arguments by default are passes by value (i.e. the values are *copied* into the local argument variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you confuse dso.h and dso.cpp.
Assuming should be dso.h...

At the top the include-guard is wrong.

```
#ifdef DSO_H
#define DSO_H
```

... should probably be

```
#ifndef DSO_H
#define DSO_H
```

Or the header will not be parsed!